# Error at use static lib(.lib) with VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, static-libraries, visual-c++-6, .lib

i make a static lib(.lib file) without "Precompiled header".  and named project_1.

**main.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; 
void display(void);
int main()
{
   cout<<"test_main\n";
   display();
   return 0;
}
```

**display.cpp**

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std; 
 void display(void) 
 { 
     cout<<"display\n"; 
 }
```

and build this project("win32 release") and copy .lib file to another project and ok.
at now i want use this .lib file.
at now make project_2.(show below) and know to compiler test.lib with this:

linker->input->Additional Dependencies->test.lib

and copy test.lib file at same folder with main.cpp(path main.cpp and test.lib is same).

**main.cpp**

```
//#include<iostream>       // ERROR 
using namespace std; 
void display(void);
int main()
{
   display();
   return 0;
}
```

but when write any `#include<...>`(example==> `#include<iostream>`) at main.cpp, compiler make ERROR.

also, if remove `display();` at main.cpp, compiler make Succeeded.

i use VS2012, and other problem, at VC++6 this problem not!.

what i do?

**List of ERROR**:

error **LNK1319**: 2 **mismatches** detected...

error **LNK2038**: mismatch detected for '**_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL**': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in main.ob....

error **LNK2038**: mismatch detected for '**RuntimeLibrary**': value '**MD_DynamicRelease**' doesn't match value '**MDd_DynamicDebug**' in main.obj....

Comment: Important piece is missing: what ERROR exactly you are getting.

Comment: i write error list at end of my post.

Comment: You are trying to link code that was compiled with completely wrong settings.  A Debug build of a static library most likely.  With the wrong compiler version as well, looks like VS2010.  Instead of a *very* nasty crash at runtime, you get a link error instead.  Contact the owner of the library and ask for an update.  And don't forget to ask for *both* a debug and a release build version.

Comment: What is the error in when use #include <...>?